# Python Tkinter enter event

Tags: python, tkinter

i'm new on Tkinter and i'm trying to make an animated button.

I'm using the enter-leave events but the click on button it's not responding very well.

My code is:

```
    imagePath = "Resources/"
    imagelist = ["boton_1.gif","boton_2.gif","boton_3.gif","boton_4.gif","boton_5.gif","boton_6.gif",
                    "boton_7.gif","boton_8.gif","boton_9.gif","boton_10.gif","boton_11.gif","boton_12.gif",
                    "boton_13.gif","boton_14.gif","boton_15.gif","boton_16.gif"]


    giflist = []
    for imagefile in imagelist:
        photo = PhotoImage(file=imagePath+imagefile)
        giflist.append(photo)

    self.photo=giflist[0]
    button = Button(buttonFrame, image=self.photo,background='orange',activebackground='lightsalmon',
                    command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ListPlayerPage))
    button.pack(pady=5)

    def enter(event):
        self.clickOnButton1 = True
        for i in range(1,8):
            button.config(image=giflist[i])
            button.update()
            time.sleep(0.1)
            if self.clickOnButton1 == False:
                break
        while (self.clickOnButton1):
            for i in range (9,15):
                button.config(image=giflist[i])
                button.update()
                time.sleep(0.08)
                if self.clickOnButton1 == False:
                    break

    def leave(event):
        self.clickOnButton1 = False
        button.config(image=self.photo)
        button.update()

    button.bind("<Enter>",enter)
    button.bind("<Leave>",leave)
```

Thanks!!

Comment: How is it not responding? Does it crash with an error, or does it simply freeze up?

Comment: It doesn't crash, sometimes you click on it, and the screen changes, and sometimes it makes nothing

Comment: So sometimes the button changes, but other times the button stays the same?

Comment: Don't use `time.sleep()` for delays in a tkinter program - they don't interact well with the tkinter mainloop. Instead, you need to use the tkinter `.after()` method. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31901206/4014959) for a simple example.

Comment: Not sure this is the cause, but I see two possible problems: 1) the PhotoImages could get garbage-collected, or 2) using `time.sleep` in a UI is generally a bad idea; better use `after`.

Comment: @tobias_k:  He's holding references to the PhotoImages in `giflist`, so shouldn't that preclude garbage collection?

Comment: An aside: `self.clickOnButton1` is confusingly named.  `self.animateButton` would be better.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Well, that depends on what is holding a reference to `giflist`. Judging from all those `self`s, this seems to be inside a method. Then again, the `giflist` could "survive" in the closures of `enter` and `leave`, not 100% sure.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: PhotoImages are weird see the note at the end of the [PhotoImage docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm). But as  tobias_k says, without a [mcve] it's hard to know for sure.

Comment: FWIW, here's an [example I wrote](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31498692/4014959) that keeps a ref to the PhotoImage as an attribute on the button (of course, that technique's not so applicable for this code). If you comment out the `b.photo = photo` line at the end of the loop only the last button gets an image.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You seem to be iterating over pictures -- are you trying to create an animated button? There are better ways to accomplish that than to use sleep and infinite loops that call `update`.  If we knew better what you were trying to accomplish we might be able to give better answers.

Comment: Brian Oakley, yes, im trying to create an animated button, but i fall in bad way...

Comment: Thanks for your comments!!

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is definitely related to the fact you're calling `sleep`. As a good rule of thumb you should never call `sleep` in the main thread of a GUI. It prevents the GUI from processing *all* events, including screen refreshes.

Generally speaking, you should also avoid calling `update`. It can result in nested event loops, if during the processing of `update` you end up calling a method that again calls `update`.

Here's a really simple example of solution that creates a button that can be animated. It uses `after` to iterate over a list of text strings, one new string every half second. This example will animate forever, but you can easily have it show each item only once. This modifies the text to make the example shorter, but you can easily modify it to change images instead of text.

```
import Tkinter as tk # use tkinter for python 3.x
class AnimatedButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._job = None

    def cancel_animation(self):
        if self._job is not None:
            self.after_cancel(self._job)
            self._job = None

    def animate(self, textlist):
        text = textlist.pop(0)
        textlist.append(text)
        self.configure(text=text)
        self._job = self.after(500, self.animate, textlist)
```

You use it like any other Button, but you can call `animate` to start animation and `cancel_animate` to cancel it:

```
button = AnimatedButton(root, width=10)
data = ["one","two","three","four","five","six"]
button.bind("<Enter>", lambda event: button.animate(data))
button.bind("<Leave>", lambda event: button.cancel_animation())
```

Comment: Thanks!!  I will try to do this example but with images. 

I think that the update() method are blocking the onclick event().. therefore, when i click on it, it's busy changing images and don't pay attention to my click.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the Bryan Oakley example and found a nice solution!

First of all, this is an animated button with a bit complex animation. I have 16 images. The firts one is the base image. Then i have eight images that are the first part of the animation. The rest of the images are the loop part of the animation.

When you put the mouse over the button, the animation starts.

Here is the code!:

```
import Tkinter as tk # use tkinter for python 3.x

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")

class AnimatedButton(tk.Button):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._job = None
        self.i = 1

    def cancel_animation(self,image):
        self.configure(image=image)
        self.i = 1
        if self._job is not None:
            self.after_cancel(self._job)
            self._job = None


    def animate(self, imagelist):
        image = imagelist[self.i]
        self.i+=1
        if self.i == (len(imagelist)-1):
            self.i = 9
        self.configure(image=image)
        self._job = self.after(80, self.animate, imagelist)


imagePath = "Resources/"
imagelist = ["boton_1.gif","boton_2.gif","boton_3.gif","boton_4.gif","boton_5.gif","boton_6.gif",
                "boton_7.gif","boton_8.gif","boton_9.gif","boton_10.gif","boton_11.gif","boton_12.gif",
                "boton_13.gif","boton_14.gif","boton_15.gif","boton_16.gif"]

giflist = []
for imagefile in imagelist:
    photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=imagePath+imagefile)
    giflist.append(photo)

image = giflist[0]
button = AnimatedButton(root,image = image)
button.bind("<Enter>", lambda event: button.animate(giflist))
button.bind("<Leave>", lambda event: button.cancel_animation(image))

button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Thank's!!!